# webView not working properly inside a TapgestureHandler

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview, react-native-gesture-handler

I am working on an app that requires detecting click on the screen so I've used TapGestureHandler from react-native gesture handler and that's work fine except for the fact that my webView stop detecting clicking on buttons inside it I mean buttons of websites, not my app buttons

To Reproduce:
you have to put a webView inside component and put any website with buttons and try to click them

Expected behavior:
buttons must be clickable to do some functions inside the webView

Environment:

OS: android
OS version: 10
react-native version: 61.5
react-native-webview version: 10.10.2